# Who would win, RLIMIT_NPROC or user namespaces?

Tags: ulimit, resources, userns

Depending on configuration, unprivileged (non-root) processes can create a user namespace.

`RLIMIT_NPROC` limits the number of processes *per user*.

If I enter a user namespace, can I create processes with different UIDs, and hence exceed my real `RLIMIT_NPROC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem so.

```
$ unshare -r
# ulimit -u 1000
# sh -c 'for i in $(seq 998); do sleep 1& done' >/dev/null
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
... (i.e. more than one error - so I guess my existing processes were already counted)
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Similarly:

```
$ unshare -r
# ulimit -u 1002
# sh -c 'for i in $(seq 100); do sleep 1& done' >/dev/null
# sleep 2
# for i in $(seq 10); do unshare -r sh -c 'for i in $(seq 100); do sleep 1& done' >/dev/null; done
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Running `ulimit -u 1000` inside `unshare -r` does not affect my user outside of the user namespace.  Ah - this is because `ulimit -u` always sets a limit inside the process.  But [when the limit is checked in fork()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/kernel/fork.c#L1781), we compare the RLIMIT_NPROC for that process, against the total number of processes of the "real" UID, i.e. from the point of view of the "root" namespace.

So as far as I can see, this all works pretty nicely.

---

Incidentally, I notice you can't use user namespaces to create processes with multiple different UIDs, if you are not privileged.

```
$ unshare -r
# id -u
0
# setpriv --ruid 1 sh
setpriv: setresuid failed: Invalid argument
```

The rules for this aspect are explained e.g. by Michael Kerrisk in [Namespaces in operation, part 5: User namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532593/).

Answer (score 2):

There's a general principle that having namespaces doesn't give you any additional privileges. There's nothing that you can do to the rest of the system with multiple namespaces that you couldn't do with a single namespace. What namespaces give you is the additional ability to apply additional restrictions to some of your processes.

`RLIMIT_NPROC` is the maximum number of processes you can create. If some of these processes are in namespaces, they may have fewer privileges, but they still count as one process. All of these processes are processes in the outer namespaces, anyway. They may have different UIDs *inside* the namespace, but outside the namespace, they're your processes.

Comment: Yep. There were 2 things confusing me about how this would work. 1) This resource is per-user (`struct_user::processes` field). Answer: since the RLIMIT value is still per-process, the namespaced process can't interfere with the RLIMIT of your "un-namespaced" processes. 2) If you had multiple UIDs inside a namespace, you *would* have access to multiple independent NPROC resources. Answer: you can't get multiple UIDs inside a namespace unless you can get multiple UIDs outside the namespace. LXC can do it using a privileged helper. https://stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/